# sorting within the keys of group by

Tags: pandas

I have a group by table as follows, I want to sort by `index` within the keys `['CPUCore', Offline_RetetionAge']` (need to keep the structure of `['CPUCore', Offline_RetetionAge']`)  how should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem `dtype` of your second level is `object`, what is obviously `string`, so if use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) it sorts alphanumeric:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CPUCore':[2,2,2,3,3],
                    'Offline_RetetionAge':['100','1','12','120','15'],
                   'index':[11,16,5,4,3]}).set_index(['CPUCore','Offline_RetetionAge'])

print (df)
                             index
CPUCore Offline_RetetionAge       
2       100                     11
        1                       16
        12                       5
3       120                      4
        15                       3
```

```
print (df.index.get_level_values('Offline_RetetionAge').dtype)
object


print (df.sort_index())
                             index
CPUCore Offline_RetetionAge       
2       1                       16
        100                     11
        12                       5
3       120                      4
        15                       3

#change multiindex - cast level Offline_RetetionAge to int
new_index = list(zip(df.index.get_level_values('CPUCore'),
                     df.index.get_level_values('Offline_RetetionAge').astype(int)))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = df.index.names)


print (df.sort_index())
                             index
CPUCore Offline_RetetionAge       
2       1                       16
        12                       5
        100                     11
3       15                       3
        120                      4
```

EDIT by comment:

```
print (df.reset_index()
         .sort_values(['CPUCore','index'])
         .set_index(['CPUCore','Offline_RetetionAge']))
                             index
CPUCore Offline_RetetionAge       
2       12                       5
        100                     11
        1                       16
3       15                       3
        120                      4
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but want to sort by "index column", not by index

Comment: Ok, so you need `print (df.reset_index().sort_values(['CPUCore','index']).set_index(['CPUCore','Offline_RetetionAge']))` ?

Comment: I have a followed up question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868845/selecting-top-3-elements-within-groupby

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is this:
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import Series, DataFrame

```
# create what I believe you tried to ask
df = DataFrame( \
   [[11,'reproducible'], [16, 'example'], [5, 'a'], [4, 'create'], [9,'!']])
df.columns = ['index', 'bla']
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[2]*4+[3],[10,100,1000,11,512]], \
                                  names=['CPUCore', 'Offline_RetentionAge'])

# sort by values and afterwards by index where sort_remaining=False preserves
# the order of index
df = df.sort_values('index').sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False)

print df
```

The statement `sort_values` sorts the values by index and the `sort_index` restores the grouping by multiindex without changing the order of index for rows with the same `CPUCore`.

I don't know what a "group by table" is supposed to be. If you have a pd.GroupBy object, you won't be able to use sort_values() like that. 
You might have to rethink what you group by or use `functools.partial` and `DataFrame.apply`

Output:

```
                              index           bla
 CPUCore Offline_RetentionAge                     
 2       11                        4        create
         1000                      5             a
         10                       11  reproducible
         100                      16       example
 3       512                       9             !
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a followed up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868845/selecting-top-3-elements-within-groupby