# Selecting top 3 elements within groupby

Tags: pandas

Given the following pandas group by table, how could I get the top 3 `index` for `Offline_RentetionAge` within each `CPUCore`, and keep the structure of the table?

[image]

For the above the result should be

> ```
>    CPUCore  Offline_RetetionAge  index
> 0        i7     183                4184
> 1               7                  1981
> 2               30                  471
> 3        i5     ..                ...
> ```

Comment: What is `print (df.index.get_level_values('Offline_RetetionAge').dtype)` ?

Comment: @jezrael it's object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) if values in `index column` are sorted:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).head(3)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CPUCore':['i7'] * 4 + ['i5'] * 4,
                    'Offline_RetetionAge':['100','1','12','120','15','10','20','3'],
                   'index':[11,16,5,4,30,18,2,1]})
       .set_index(['CPUCore','Offline_RetetionAge'])

print (df)
                             index
CPUCore Offline_RetetionAge       
i7      100                     11
        1                       16
        12                       5
        120                      4
i5      15                      30
        10                      18
        20                       2
        3                        1

df = df.groupby(level=0).head(3)
print (df)
                             index
CPUCore Offline_RetetionAge       
i7      100                     11
        1                       16
        12                       5
i5      15                      30
        10                      18
        20                       2
```

Comment: oops, sorry, need groupby by first level only.

Comment: Thank you for accepting. small advice - better is use text of sample data as `picture` in question, because text of picture cannot be copied. People of SO hate it and very often downvote question for it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869206/generate-seaborn-countplot-using-column-value-as-count

Comment: Seaborn is for me a bit unknown, so I can try, but I think somebody will be faster.

Comment: But for me is one thing unclear - column for `hue` - `hue="Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType"` is missing from `df` ? Can you add it to sample of data?

Comment: The hue now is `Offline_RentetionAge`, that one just an example..the difficulty is that the count is in a column.

Comment: Ok, I find something like `sns.barplot(x="CPUCore", y="index", hue='Offline_RetetionAge', data=df.reset_index())` - is it correct? Do you need it?

Comment: Maybe some parameters is necessary changed, but maybe it is wrong - I am not sure if understand your question.