# Generate Seaborn Countplot using column value as count

Tags: pandas, seaborn

For the following table

```
                             count_value
CPUCore Offline_RetentionAge       
i7      183                    4184
        7                      1981
        30                      471
i5      183                    2327
        7                       831
        30                      250
Pentium 183                     333
        7                       125
        30                       43
2       183                     575
        7                       236
        31                       96
```

Is it possible to generate a seaborn countplot (or normal countplot) like the following (generated using `sns.countplot(x='CPUCore', hue="Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType", data=dfCombined_df)`)

[image]

Problem here is that I need to use the `count_value` as count, rather then really go and count the `Offline_RetentionAge`

Comment: Can you show actual data with the `Offline_BackupSchemaIncrementType` column included?

Comment: @IanS The hue now is `Offline_RentetionAge`, that one just an example..the difficulty is that the count is in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [seaborn.barplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
sns.barplot(x="count_value", y="index", hue='Offline_RetentionAge', data=df.reset_index())
```

[image: graph]